# One script modifying the other's output?

Tags: javascript, image, numbers

I'm having difficulties making these two scripts operate together.

The first script changes numbers 0-9 to its respective image, while the second displays a count-up occurring at a set interval/increment. I don't know why (on account of my noobness) but these two don't get along.

This is how I've been trying to run these together:

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
<!–
counterimages(input);
//–></script>
<div id="counter"></div>
```

Here's the .js file:

```
function counterimages(input) {
var output = ""

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    var chr = input.substring(i, i + 1)
    if (chr == '£') {
        output += '<img border="0" src="img/pound.gif">';
    } else if (chr == '.') {
        output += '<img border="0" src="img/dot.gif">';
    } else {
        output += '<img border="0" src="http://eatiply3.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/'+(chr+1)+'.png">';
    }
return output;
}
}

var START_DATE = new Date("October 21, 2012 22:30:00"); // put in the starting date here
var INTERVAL = 1; // refresh interval in seconds
var INCREMENT = 769.2;  // increase per tick (1/0.0013 ~ 769)
var START_VALUE = 35000; // initial value when it's the start date
var count = 0;

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
var now = new Date();
count = parseInt((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
$('#counter').html(count.toFixed(0));

window.setInterval( function(){
count += INCREMENT; 
$('#counter').html(count.toFixed(0));
}, msInterval);

});
```

Comment: `input` is not defined when you call `counterimages(input);`

Comment: thanks, how would you recommend I define the input?

Comment: I guess it's the number that the other code is spitting out. You probably need to pass that number into `counterImages` rather than sticking it in the document, and then put the result in the document.

Comment: So they would actually have to be written as one script? Since I can't just plug in the <div id="counter"></div> into the input correct?